# Sqlite Error : FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to update the employee data in sqlite. Employee ssn number of two data is mistakenly swapped and now when i try to swap the data again with the code below:

```
UPDATE employee SET SSN=’666884444’  WHERE SSN = ‘123456789’; 
UPDATE employee SET SSN=’123456789’ WHERE SSN = ‘666884444’;
```

it shows me the following error:

```
[16:51:19] Error while executing SQL query on database 'Company': 
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Can someone please guide me with the query?

Comment: One of those numbers probably doesn't exist in the table that employee.ssn is related too. You can temporarily turn off foreign key checks with a pragma and turn them back on after doing this.

Comment: Also, I don't think that attempt to swap will actually work.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

1. Change the FK constraint to **DEFERRED**.  Syntax is `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`.
2. Do your updates inside a `BEGIN/COMMIT` transaction block.